# How to add trailing icon to MDCTextInputControllerFilled in Swift?

Tags: swift, material-design

I want to add the password toggle icon to the text field in Swift and I am using the material design library, in specific, the MDC text input filled.
How can I add the trailing icon to the right of the text field programmatically? I have seen that the trailing icon is part of the material design but can't find its documentation.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I am using **MDCOutlinedTextField** type of text field and I achieved a trailing icon using the following method:

```
let tf = MDCOutlinedTextField()
let eyeIcon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_eye"))
    
tf.trailingView = eyeIcon
tf.trailingViewMode = .always
```